# Azure Linux B1s VM - Jenkins Sever installed but the home page is not opening

Tags: linux, azure, jenkins, azure-virtual-machine

I have tried with the Azure Free services - Linux VM B1s of 1 GB RAM, installed the Jenkins, allowed ports 80, 22, 8080, logged to Jenkins through VM's public_ip:8080 in the browser and entered the password fetched from the Jenkins Server.

After that, I'm unable to get the home page of Jenkins. It is showing as blank page:

[image: AzureLinuxVMB1SJenkins]

Where I have tried with the commands listed in the Azure [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/jenkins/configure-on-linux-vm) for Jenkins Server installation, as it also allowed the same ports and created with DSv1 Series of 3.5 GB RAM.

I'm able to get the Home page of the Jenkins Server as it shows like Install Plugins menu.

The only difference is RAM and vCPU's.
Where as in the Jenkins installation [document](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/), it is mentioned that the minimum hardware requirement is 1 GB of RAM and 256 GB ROM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possibilities why you might be getting a blank page when you try to access the `Jenkins home page` on your `VM` with size of`Azure B1s`.

The `Jenkins homepage` may not load properly if your `VM` has insufficient `RAM` or `CPU` resources. In such cases, it might struggle to display the page correctly. Please check the `RAM` usage on your `VM`. Additionally, browser cache can sometimes cause display issues. Consider accessing Jenkins from a different browser or clearing your current browser's cache.

I have installed `Jenkins Server` on `VM` with size `B1s` of `1 GB RAM`

[image]

I can open the `Jenkins homepage` with a slight delay using a `VM` configured with `1GB` of `RAM` and `1 CPU`.

[image]

I would suggest you follow the Jenkins requirement for small team configuration for smooth setup on Jenkins on your VM. I used standard B2ms with 2vCPU and 8 GB of RAM.

[image]

Once you are done with your VM setup, make sure to allow port 8080.

[image]

Assuming that you have verified other pre-requisites like jdk version as below-

[image]

Start with the Jenkins setup process as below-
Pull the Jenkins repo and append the package to the system.

[image]

Update your system `sudo apt update`

[image]

```
curl -fsSL https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins.io-2023.key | sudo tee \
  /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc > /dev/null
```

&

```
echo deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc] \
https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian binary/ | sudo tee \
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list > /dev/null
```

install Jenkins `apt install jenkins -y`

[image]

Now Go to the Azure Portal`enter code here` console. copy the public IP address from the overview section and paste it into your browser http://your-public-ip:8080 and it should work. If it is not loading up on your browser, just verify if you can access Jenkins locally using `curl localhost:8080`

[image]

[image]

if it fails please verify if you have opened port 8080 as mentioned above. If the port is allowed then you should be able to access Jenkins on your browser as below-

[image]

You can get the credentials using `cat` for the path it shows on your unlock Jenkins page

```
sudo cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

copy and paste the password in the admin password, and install the default suggested plugins and you can access Jenkins as below-

[image]

Once the plugins are installed as below

[image]

you will be redirected to the login page, set your credentials accordingly and click on next.

[image]

You have logged into the Jenkins dashboard.

[image]

[image]

Reference document :  [Official Jenkins Installation document](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/)

Comment: Hello @VenkatV, I don't require step by step process of installing jenkins - infact it's not my original question. And I fixed the issue with 1 GB of RAM which is minimum H/w requirement mentioned in the Jenkins Installation docs itself.

Step by Step answering without the proper fix or suggestion to the question doesn't be a solution.

Anyways! Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Hi @TheMassacre  I have highlighted the main concern in the first sentence and provided step-by-step instructions for clear understanding. Other community members facing the same issue can quickly resolve it by following the answer.